# Converting NodeJs to python

Tags: python, node.js, discord

I hope that it is appropriate to ask whether someone with NodeJS experience can convert this code to python. I have already translated some small tiny bits, but I am getting errors when I run my code, I have tried for hours but had no luck in figuring out what my issue is. I have no NodeJs experience for clarification. Many Thanks in advance if do it :)

```
require('dotenv').config() // Load .env file
const axios = require('axios')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

function getPrices() {


    // API for price data.
    axios.get(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=${process.env.PREFERRED_CURRENCY}&ids=${process.env.COIN_ID}`).then(res => {
        // If we got a valid response
        if(res.data && res.data[0].current_price && res.data[0].price_change_percentage_24h) {
            let currentPrice = res.data[0].current_price || 0 // Default to zero
            let priceChange = res.data[0].price_change_percentage_24h || 0 // Default to zero
            let symbol = res.data[0].symbol || '?' 
            client.user.setPresence({
                game: {
                    // Example: "Watching -5,52% | BTC"
                    name: `${priceChange.toFixed(2)}% | ${symbol.toUpperCase()}`,
                    type: 3 // Use activity type 3 which is "Watching"
                }
            })

            client.guilds.find(guild => guild.id === process.env.SERVER_ID).me.setNickname(`${(currentPrice).toLocaleString().replace(/,/g,process.env.THOUSAND_SEPARATOR)}${process.env.CURRENCY_SYMBOL}`)

            console.log('Updated price to', currentPrice)
        }
        else
            console.log('Could not load player count data for', process.env.COIN_ID)

    }).catch(err => console.log('Error at api.coingecko.com data:', err))
}

// Runs when client connects to Discord.
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in as', client.user.tag)

    getPrices() // Ping server once on startup
    // Ping the server and set the new status message every x minutes. (Minimum of 1 minute)
    setInterval(getPrices, Math.max(1, process.env.MC_PING_FREQUENCY || 1) * 60 * 1000)
})

// Login to Discord
client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: You may have issues with the libraries you're using. An exact equivalent may not exist.

Comment: I do believe I have the correct libraries downloaded, I'm just not sure about some of the coding terminology that NodeJS utilises and I am unsure what that conversion would be in python @vinalti

Comment: Maybe we could give a more helpful answer if you told which which specific parts you were having trouble with. Or maybe we could see what you tried in Python?